# How come 0.7 - 0.5 - 0.2 => -5.551115123125783e-17?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, decimal

I have no idea how to deal with problems like this:

```
0.7. - 0.5. - 0.2 # => -5.551115123125783e-17
```

[An article](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info) links to [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and [THE FLOATING-POINT GUIDE](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/). They describe why some approximation, and therefore inaccuracy, is unavoidable. But I still have no idea. Any explanation of why the result is remote from expected as well as why a calculator does well with a problem would be helpful for understanding of the problem.

Comment: 1) **problems like this**: it's not a problem, it's a fact. What is your problem? 2) **remote from expected**: Who is the subject? It is not remove from expected to me, or to many people using this site. At least, describe what it is that is expected. 3) **why a calculator does well [better?]**: Not clear what you mean by this. I don't think an ordinary calculator does any better than a computer, if that is what you claim.

Comment: That's not "remote from expected." It's correct to better than one in a million-billion. Even assuming that's terrible, it's because floating-point numbers are (as you point out) *not accurate*. The floating-point standard sacrifices precision for a wider scale. Calculators solve the problem either by not using floating-point numbers or by rounding outside the precision.

Comment: @sawa A typical pocket calculator computes with base-10 floating-point directly, at least as much because conversions at each step for displaying results would be expensive as because of user expectations. Regardless, as a result, a pocket calculator computes `0.7. - 0.5. - 0.2` exactly.

Comment: @PascalCuoq How does that make a calculator better? It won't calculate  `0.700000000000001 - 0.5 - 0.2` (with more or less `0`s depending on the particular calculator) exactly.

Comment: @sawa I know what you mean but your example is terrible. The calculator will not compute `0.700000000000001 - 0.5 - 0.2` because it won't represent `0.700000000000001`. And it is easy for the human operator to understand that it won't represent `0.700000000000001` intuitively, because it won't display or parse `0.700000000000001`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have worked out from the resources you link to floating point numbers are an approximation. You are right that with floating point numbers you are going to have inaccuracies representation.

In most cases these small inaccuracies end up mostly cancelling out when performing calculations. E.g. something just larger than 5 + something just smaller than 3 is something almost exactly 8.

The accuracy that floating point can represent values varies depending on the values themselves. Numbers that are between -1 and 0 and 0 and 1 are more difficult to represent accurately the closer they are to 0. Numbers outside this range get less accurate the further away from 0 they are.

The case you have shown is one where the inaccuracies in representing .7, .5 and .2 have all added up to an even larger inaccuracy in the result.

As for calculators, most calculators don't actually use binary floating point numbers. They use either arbitrary precision fixed point ones, or decimal floating point instead. Fixed point numbers don't have the kind of inaccuracies of precision that floating point numbers do. This comes at the expense of the range of numbers that they are capable of representing though. Decimal floating point doesn't have the same kind of error of representation, as it doesn't have to convert numbers from decimal to binary before storing them. It can still suffer from rounding errors though.

Comment: Actually there is no inaccuracy in representing .5.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are (usually) binary and some fractions can only be approximated by binary fractions with a finite number of digits, leading to the behaviour that you're seeing.
Note that exactly the same problem occurs with decimal fractions. For example (to 6 decimal places)

```
    1.0 / 3.0 = 0.333333
    3.0 * 0.333333 = 0.999999
```

I think that the reason why binary approximations of fractions can seem suprising whilst decimal ones don't is simply that we're *so* familiar with the latter that we barely even notice them any more!